# NaCl and curl - can't connect to server

Tags: c++, curl, google-nativeclient

I'm new to NaCl and now I'm starting to have some issues with this. I'm trying to load some data into C++ part of the application from C++ code and I know that I can't access files on HDD from NaCl. So, what I tried to do, was to use curl library to load this files via http from localhost.

So I set up NaCl environment, added curl - everything built fine, then I had an issue that curl couldn't resolve host name, but hopefully I overcame this issue, but then curls says that it can't connect to server (error code 7). I don't know what might be the issue.

I start chrome using this command:

```
google-chrome 127.0.0.1:5103/myapp --allow-nacl-socket-api=127.0.0.1 
--no-sandbox --load-extension="/home/user/Desktop/nacl_sdk/pepper_49/getting_started/web/" 
--enable-nacl --user-data-dir="/home/user/Desktop/chrome-dir/"
```

And code that is trying to load data from localhost is as follows:

```
static size_t data_write(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
  printf("start data_write\n");
  if (userp) {
    std::stringstream& data = *static_cast<std::stringstream*>(userp);
    std::streamsize len = size * nmemb;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      data << buf[i];
    }
    return len;
  }
  printf("end data_write\n");
  return 0;
}

CURLcode curl_read(const std::string& url, std::stringstream& os, long timeout = 300) {
  CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

  printf("CURL_READ\n");

  if (curl) {
    printf("curl is not null\n");
    if (CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
                                             &data_write)) &&
        CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L)) &&
        CURLE_OK ==
            (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L)) &&
        CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, &os)) &&
        CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout)) &&
        CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()))) {
      printf("START curl perform\n");
      code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      printf("CURL ERROR (%d) = %s\n", code, curl_easy_strerror(code));
      printf("END curl perform\n");
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return code;
}
```

And the output from console is:

```
Init curl
Loading data from: http://127.0.0.1/assets/model.obj
CURL_READ
curl is not null
START curl perform
CURL ERROR (7) = Couldn't connect to server
END curl perform
```

What might be the issue? Is it even possible to use curl in NaCl?

Comment: Can you try to use the command line to see if the file is accessible (curl http://127.0.0.1/assets/model.obj)? Also did you have the host listed in permissions (permissions: ['http://localhost/*', 'http://127.0.0.1'])?

Comment: Still doesn't work. And yes, I can access http://127.0.0.1/assets/model.obj via browser without any problems.

Comment: actually the permissions in manifest.json should be `["http://127.0.0.1/*"]`, SO editor modified it for some reason. let me know if that helps.